# CMS or Framework for my website?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, drupal, content-management-system

I'm a programmer and for a couple of days I was asking myself: Should I use a CMS or a Framework to build my website?

I've learn Laravel (a PHP framework) that I am pretty skilled with it. This said, I tried last week to build a website using a CMS (Wordpress and Drupal) but OH MY I feel like there's no customization possible compared to a framework. I feel like you have some things preset that you can customize and that's it. So I wonder what to take to do a website that will be used to present a company's product and services.

Thanks for all the responses! Share your experience programers ;)

Answer (score 1):

While I prefer Joomla, each CMS has it's advantages. WordPress is great for blog and smaller site, while Joomla allows a developer to add more sophisticated services and features.

The advantage of using most CMSs is that they already provide an admin interface, user validation, and a lot of other features. Each can be customized, and some offer hundreds or even thousands of extensions that can allow you to quickly add new features to a site.

A CMS is a big step up from a framework. While there can be a steep learning curve, it can allow you to save many hours in creating and maintaining a site.

As an example, I can set up a fully working site in just a few hours using Joomla with many advanced features. It also provides a certain amount of consistency for me as a site developer and site maintainer. I see the same admin interface on all of the sites I create and maintain.

I have on occasion used a framework instead of a CMS, usually due to customer requirements. It can take an order of magnitude more time to create most sites using a framework instead of a CMS. However, using a framework can allow you to do some things that don't work in a CMS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Sloan Thrasher! There's one thing I wonder. Can we code when we use a CMS? Like in Laravel I could code a controller that brings data to my view and vice-versa, is it possible to code using a CMS?

Comment: Absolutely! In the Joomla and Wordpress worlds, that how modules, components and templates are made. I also use an extension for a lot of DB related tasks call ChronoForms and ChronoConnection.

Comment: Do you know a good tutorial where I could learn the programming side of a CMS like Joomla, Drupal or Wordpress?

Comment: Try https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=joomla+extension+development+tutorial&oq=jooml+extension+de&gs_l=hp.3.1.0i13k1l2j0i13i30k1l8.2620.19540.0.23402.30.27.3.0.0.0.155.2845.8j17.25.0....0...1.1.64.hp..2.27.2732.0..0j0i131k1j0i3k1j0i10k1j0i13i10i30k1j0i13i10k1.WFt5kgl00zo

Answer (score -1):

I have used Joomla, WordPress only for my projects and i'm learning som PHP frameworks.

My advice:

1. If you expect the site to grow go for a CMS. Check the one that has best and more documentation, forums with answered questions related to your future plans, good amount of plugins, easy to modify the CMS itself so other non-programmers can access/check/modify data, etc...
2. For small projects go check frameworks obviously.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Memristor, I want to build a website, like I said, to present the services and products a company offers. I'm not good at doing front-end work so probably a CMS could be a good choice for me?

Comment: @ettdro I modified Joomla extensively with PHP/JS if that's what you mean. It was not easy at the beginning but a lot is done already, a lot of Youtube videos and "free" books are there. Just trial and error. The main problem was the behavior of some plugins applied to a component that i had previously modified... always unexpected, so keep record of what you modify. A good advice would be, once you choose a CMS try to make small templates, plugins, etc... so you can understand quickly why other people have done things the way they did. Hope it helped.

Comment: Ok! Cause I feel like a CMS is only a drag and drop thing that you can insert some HTML and sometimes CSS at some place. Are there some files that you can change in the CMS? Do you know any good tutorial I could follow for this?